# Ajax Jquery always give Error

Tags: jquery, ajax

here is my code

```
<script>
    function undKet(nik){
        var action = "nik=" + nik;
        $.ajax({ 
            cache: true, 
            url:'und_ket.php',
            type:'get',
            dataType:'html',
            data: action,

            error: function() {
                alert("Gagal mengirim data!");
            },

            success:function(data)
            { 
                var _html= $(data);
                //do some thing with html eg: _html.find('div').addClass('red')
                alert("Data berhasil di kembalikan");
                parent.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

It always run error function, I tried remove dataType but it doesn't work.
I need help with that code. Thank You

Comment: Then debug the problem. There's not enough information here to help you as the JS code is not the issue. Open the console and check the error that's coming back from your server and go from there

Answer (score 0):

To better debug this and have a better idea of what is going wrong let me give some tips for debugging with chrome dev tools that you can open by pressing `F12` on your page.

- Check the console tab for java script errors, like for example if one of your variables is null.
- Check the network tab on the request going for your page, what the respond code is e.g. if it is 404 then you specified the wrong path, if it is 500, the request got to your PHP script but an error was thrown.
- There should be additional info in the actual response of the request if the response code doesn't offer insight.

A common issue, especially with vanilla PHP is that the responseType and dataType on your ajax request is wrong, e.g. the request says `responseType: "json"` but your PHP script is returning HTML